# R: Splitting time-series data based on conditions

Tags: r, split, time-series

I am looking to split a time-series (price data) based on whether the following data-point shows an increase, decrease or no change.

Example:

In the set `as.ts(c(1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1))` the datapoints followed by up would be `1, 2, 3, 4`.

I suspect this can be neatly solved with an `if` function, but am not sure how to specify the following row, nor am I sure as to how the syntax would look.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's your expected output? two time series? what did you try so far?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel the expected output would be 3 data frames, one for each outcome (followed by up, followed by down and no change).

I have tried using an `if` function and the `split` function, but have been unable to specify the next row as a condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of two approaches:

1) Using `diff` as follows:

```
ifelse(diff(ts) > 0, 'up', ifelse(diff(ts) < 0, 'down', 'none'))
```

Output is:

```
Time Series:
Start = 2 
End = 10 
Frequency = 1 
[1]   up   up   up   up none down down down down
```

2) Using the `lag` function from `dplyr` package:

```
ifelse(ts > lag(ts), 'up', ifelse(ts < lag(ts), 'down', 'none'))
```

Output is as follows:

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 10 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] <NA>   up   up   up   up none down down down down
```

You can replace the first NA by using a default in the `lag` or separately.

EDIT: Based on additional output desired per comments below, I am editing the answer:

You can save the result of the above in a newts - for example, and extract the original values that belong to each of the 'moves' as follows:

```
newts <- c('up', ifelse(diff(ts) > 0, 'up', ifelse(diff(ts) < 0, 'down', 'none')))
sapply(unique(newts), function(x) ts[newts == x])
```

Output is as follows:

```
$up
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$none
[1] 5

$down
[1] 4 3 2 1
```

These are three lists. You can do whatever else you want with them, or combine them into other data structures as desired.

NOTE: I am pre-pending the `newts` with up since the first element is an orphan with no move. Depending on how you want things to output, you may want to adjust this value to your taste.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it works perfectly. I realise I didn't specify that in the question, hence why I accepted your answer, but how would I go about recording the values followed by a change in a separate timeseries?

Comment: If you saved that above result in - let us say - `newts`. You can get everything after the first change to `down` using something like this: `newts[which.max(newts == 'down'):length(newts)]`

Comment: Again thanks, my question was more aimed at how to get the value corresponding with say `down` for each occurence into a timeseries.

Apologies for being unclear.

Comment: I edited the answer with what I think you are asking.

Comment: Legend! much appreciated.